# Como filtrar la data de un arreglo en angular

Tags: javascript, array, angular, typescript, filtro

estoy tratando de filtrar a todos los usuarios activos en un componente de angular, utilizando un servicio, cargo toda la data pero no se como filtrarla.

Este es mi componente

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UsuariosService } from '../../services/services.index';
import { Usuario } from 'src/app/models/usuario';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-panel',
  templateUrl: './admin-panel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-panel.component.css']
})
export class AdminPanelComponent implements OnInit {


  usuariosData: Usuario[] = [];
  total: number;
  total_activos: Usuario[] = [];

  constructor(private usuario: UsuariosService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAllusers();
  }


  // optiene todos los usuarios
  getAllusers() {
    this.usuario.getAllUsers().subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.usuariosData = data.usuarios;
      this.total = this.usuariosData.length;
      this.total_activos = this.usuariosData.filter(activos => usuario.estado ==1  )

    });
  }   

}
```

En esa API el estado activo es un 1 he inactivo un 0.

¿Podrían Ayudarme?

Comment: Saludos. A mi parecer el error lo tienes en `this.usuariosData.filter(activos => usuario.estado ==1  )` debe ser `this.usuariosData.filter(activos => activos.estado ==1  )` (PD: No olvides poner el fin de instrucción en cada sentencia como corresponda). Ver https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter y https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cambia la palabra activo por usuario

```
this.total_activos = this.usuariosData.filter(usuario => usuario.estado ==1  )
```

Recuerda que filter recorre un array y a cada elemento de ese array tu le asignas un nombre en este caso **usuario** tu lo tenias como **activo**.

Suerte :)